# Moralis API can't find meta data

Tags: nft, moralis

I'm attempting to retrieve metadata from [these NFTs](https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0xcdfea41c4a8e70fb4838426069483dc50cbf5041/267) using the [Moralis APIs](https://admin.moralis.io/web3Api#). So far I'm partially successfull with the API enpoint  `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/nft/{address}/{ID}?chain=matic&format=decimal` I'm able to get the data for any NFT with an ID of 1 - 670. Any NFT with an ID higher than 671 gives the response `{ "message": "No metadata found! Try again later" }`

After attempting a bit on my own I asked the question on the [moralis forum](https://forum.moralis.io/t/no-metadata-found-for-some-nfts/12595). They advised me to re-sync the metadata / uri, which I did using the API `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/nft/{address}/{ID}/metadata/resync?chain=matic&flag=uri&mode=sync`. This gives the response `{ "status": "The metadata could not be updated! Try again later" }` testing the API to grab the meta data again confirms that nothing was changed.

Any solutions to this issue or alternative ways to get the metadata are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Moralis now have automatic metadata refresh, so your metadata should be available and automatically updated if there's any change to the metadata

However, if the metadata is not IPFS-based, then you still need to call the resync APIs

Since there's a problem on your end with the resync API, let me know what input you have so I can test it out on my end

Otherwise, let me know if you still have an issue on that

Answer (score 0):

Some NFTs still return null or empty tokenUri or metadata. Token URI is IPFS-based.

[Empty Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h31uE.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).